# multiplying multiple matrices at as one big matrx multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a random number (say XX) of  m * n  matrices which needs to be multiplied with an equal number of n * x matrices.
i.e.
Set 1:  A * B   (where A is m *n and B is n * x) 
Set 2:  C * D   ( where  C is m * n and D is n * x) 
... 
Set XX:  X * Z    (where ...ditto)

Normally I just do these in a loop 1 by 1.

However I am assuming there must be a smarter way of doing all multiplications together.  I would very much like the output to be an  (XX * m) * x  matrix where each m * x is one set of result.

Is that possible at all?   How?

If not what can I do to not have to loop through each matrix one by one?

Would appreciate guidance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can make two block diagonal matrices and multiply them. Computationally it is going to be the same, but perhaps that is smarter.

Comment: @markvs, thanks.